# how to convert a single-byte encoded string into UTF-32?

Tags: c++, unicode, string-conversion

I know code page of the input string, for example CP 852, now I need to make it to the universal UCS-4 format. What function I should use. I'm doing it under WinXP with MingW.

Comment: if mingw has libiconv in it (which I think it does, I just haven't worked with it in a while), this what you probably need. http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.3.html

Comment: What have you found? What options have you considered? What have you tried?

Comment: Well I tried to include iconv.h without success. I have no idea where to start from, all results search gives are for converting from utf to ascii or other questions with similar wording but none of them concerns what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really sure you want UTF-32 encoded strings (and I suggest doing some research first - it is almost always a bad choice), you can start with [MultiByteToWideChar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the CP 852 encoded string to UTF-16, and then write your own function to convert UTF-16 to UTF-32.

Comment: Ok, if you say so, I stick with UTF-16.